# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. Why does the bodyParser not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, syntax-error, body-parser

This is my index.js file and i think i have placed the routes after installing bodyParser but still getting the syntax error.

```
const express = require('express'); //Framework to build server side application
const morgan = require('morgan'); //Logging the nodejs requests
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //To get the JSON data
const urls = require('./db/urls');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('./public')); //If a request comes with '/' check if file is in there if it is then serve it up.
// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//     res.send('Hello, World !!');
// });
app.post('/api/shorty', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const url = await urls.create(req.body); //Passing the body data which is JSON to create function
        res.json(url);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500);
        res.json(error)
    }
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is the urls.js file,I am not getting where have i messed up to make Syntax.JSON error in this file.

```
const db = require('./connection');
const Joi = require('joi');//Schema validation

const urls = db.get('urls');
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    name : Joi.string().token().min(1).max(100).required(),
    url : Joi.string().uri({
        scheme: [
            /https?/ //get http 's' is optional
        ]
    }).required()
}).with('name','url');

//almostShorty = { 
//     name = ,
//     url =
// }

function create(almostShorty){
   const result = Joi.validate(almostShorty, schema);
   if(result.error === null){
       return urls.insert(almostShorty);//Inserting the object in the Data Base.
   }else{
       return Promise.reject(result.error);
   }
};

module.exports = {create};//Exporting the create function.
```

Comment: Can you show us what the `./db/urls` contains?

Comment: Are you sure the body is actually JSON?

Comment: @V.Sambor I have edited it check the urls.js file

Comment: If your request body is JSON and `bodyParser` is doing its job, `req.body` will be an `Object`, not a JSON string. Your comment in the code, _"Passing the body data **which is JSON** to create function"_ is incorrect